# MySQL :: How to run ANALYZE TABLE for all tables in a database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, index-statistics

I'm using MySQL 5.7

How can I run ANALYZE TABLE for all tables in a database. It should work if new tables are added to the database in future.

This is to refresh the statistics of table indexes.

Comment: Stored procedure. Cursor by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. Iteration by it. Prepared statement in.

Comment: @Akina can you pls provide some references with helpful examples?

Comment: As a first step, explore [searching result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES+PREPARE+EXECUTE). I think you will find enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Any progress on this @SatishGadhave? I can quite simply get a list of a table names, but cannot seem to pass each table name into ANALYZE TABLE, unless I have manually typed it... Seems you cannot pass a variable into ANALYZE TABLE.

Answer (score 9):

You can run

```
mysqlcheck -a --all-databases
```

Comment: Simply run `mysqlcheck -a [database]` if you want it for a specific database, it will run for all tables in the DB given by default (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html)

Comment: ```sudo mysqlcheck -a --all-databases -u root```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using InnoDB tables (which you should be):

```
SET @old_innodb_stats_on_metadata = @@global.innodb_stats_on_metadata;
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata='ON';
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db;
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = @old_innodb_stats_on_metadata;
```

For InnoDB, the actions performed by ANALYZE TABLE are also performed by merely viewing the table status, if the option I show above is ON. That is, viewing the table status, or querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, will trigger the same refresh of table statistics that ANALYZE TABLE does.

The statement `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db` shows all tables from the named schema by default, so there's no need to code a loop or anything as other answers have shown.

Comment: I love very concise things like this. Thanks !!!

Comment: Found it in the Docs (Paragraph 2 of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata). I have benchmarked your answer against mine (267 databases with 11285 tables). Yours is definitely the faster approach.

Comment: Just going to edit your answer since innodb_stats_on_metadata is GLOBAL.

Comment: MySQL Doc also says: "This option only applies when optimizer statistics are configured to be non-persistent. Optimizer statistics are not persisted to disk when innodb_stats_persistent is disabled or when individual tables are created or altered with STATS_PERSISTENT=0. "

Comment: Could you also update your answer with the caveat pointed out by @SoheilRahsaz since `innodb_stats_persistent` is enabled by default, and I confirm your solution does not update table statistics when this is enabled, and so it won't work for most DBs assuming they keep the default, which is likely for performance plan stability.

Comment: does it work for mariadb? it seems like doesnt

Comment: @Alex - I have no idea. This question was about MySQL 5.7, so I didn't check MariaDB. I also didn't check Informix, Oracle, or MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a way of getting the exact number of rows in each table in my db, and found that `ANALYZE TABLE table_name` is needed to make sure the value is correct. I could not pass a variable `table_name` into `ANALYZE TABLE`, so this is the best I could do.

In summary:

- create a stored procedure `script_to_analyse_all_tables()` which loops through each table name, producing the query `ANALYZE TABLE table_name` for each table.
- call this stored procedure
- delete this stored procedure afterwards (if you dont want it to remain)

Then, manually:

- Copy the output
- Paste & run the output in MySQL workbench.

Just update `db_name` with the name of your database before you run it.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `script_to_analyse_all_tables`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE script_to_analyse_all_tables()
BEGIN
    -- declare variables
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE this_table_name VARCHAR(256); 
    DECLARE full_statement VARCHAR(10000); 
    -- declare cursor for table names
    DECLARE cursor_table_name CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[db_name]';
    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
    -- open the cursor
    OPEN cursor_table_name;
    
    myLoop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_table_name INTO this_table_name;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE myLoop;
        END IF;
        SET full_statement = concat( IFNULL(full_statement,''), "ANALYZE TABLE ", this_table_name, ";");
    END LOOP myLoop;
    -- close the cursor
    CLOSE cursor_table_name;
    -- view results:
    SELECT full_statement as "run the following statement:";
    
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL script_to_analyse_all_tables;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `script_to_analyse_all_tables`;
```

Then check the results with:

`SELECT table_name, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[db_name]';`

Answer (score 1):

On further research, I found the following, neater answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707827/12032648

Code below lifted straight from the referenced answer, wrapped in a procedure.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `script_to_analyse_all_tables`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE script_to_analyse_all_tables()
BEGIN

# zgwp_tables_rowcounts
# TableName RowCount
# Outputs a result set listing all tables and their row counts 
# for the current database

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;
SET @dbname = DATABASE();

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
    CONCAT (
      'SELECT ''',table_name,''' as TableName, COUNT(*) as RowCount FROM ', 
       table_name, ' '
    ) 
    SEPARATOR 'UNION '  
  ) AS Qry
FROM
  information_schema.`TABLES` AS t
WHERE
  t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @dbname AND
  t.TABLE_TYPE = "BASE TABLE"
ORDER BY
  t.TABLE_NAME ASC

INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL script_to_analyse_all_tables;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `script_to_analyse_all_tables`;
```

Comment: This does not actually analyze anything, it merely gives a list of all tables with corresponding row counts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash script that will run ANALYZE TABLE against all tables in a given database

```
RUN_SQL=/tmp/analyze_all_tables.sql
RUN_LOG=/tmp/analyze_all_tables.log

MYSQL_HOST=whateverhostname
MYSQL_AUSER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_AUTH="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

DB=whateverdb

SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ANALYZE LOCAL TABLE \`',table_schema,'\`.\`',table_name,'\`;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE table_schema='${DB}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND engine IS NOT NULL"

# Create SQL Commands to run ANALYZE TABLE
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${RUN_SQL}

# Execute ANALYZE TABLE Commands
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} --table < ${RUN_SQL} > ${RUN_LOG} 2>&1
```

Here is a bash script that will run ANALYZE TABLE against all tables in all databases

```
RUN_SQL=/tmp/analyze_all_tables.sql
RUN_LOG=/tmp/analyze_all_tables.log

MYSQL_HOST=whateverhostname
MYSQL_AUSER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_AUTH="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ANALYZE LOCAL TABLE \`',table_schema,'\`.\`',table_name,'\`;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','sys','innodb')"
SQL="${SQL} AND engine IS NOT NULL"

# Create SQL Commands to run ANALYZE TABLE
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${RUN_SQL}

# Execute ANALYZE TABLE Commands
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} --table < ${RUN_SQL} > ${RUN_LOG} 2>&1
```

### NOTE

The SQL Clause `AND engine IS NOT NULL` will skip views